# Get Return value after creating record using WebAPI

Tags: acumatica

When I create a record (Case) using WebAPI, I need to get the created CaseCD. There is no return value it seems when using below method. Any Suggestion?

```
CR306000.Actions.Save
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked on Case in my project yet but have done something similar and would suggest you try below to get return value:

```
            CR306000Content CR306000 = context.CR306000GetSchema();

            CR306000Content[] CR306000Content = context.CR306000Submit
            (
                    new Command[]
                    {
                        new Value {Value = "xxxxx", LinkedCommand = CR306000.CaseSummary.BusinessAccount},
                        new Value {Value = "xxxxx", LinkedCommand = CR306000.CaseSummary.Reason},
                        ..............,
                        CR306000.Actions.Save,
                        CR306000.CaseSummary.CaseID
                    }
                );

            var CaseCD = CR306000Content[0].CaseSummary.CaseID.Value;
```